# CheckBox Style / Format

Tags: .net, wpf, checkbox

Is there a way to achieve this with a style on the CheckBox (not TextBlock)

```
<CheckBox>
  <TextBlock Text="All" Margin="-1,1,0,0" />
</CheckBox>
```

e.g.

```
<CheckBox Content="All" Style="{StaticResource CloseText}" />
```

Based on answer from Pasha
Padding does move the text
The problem here is the Style applies all properties but padding
See below:  CB1 and CB2 do not have the same padding
ContentTemplate does work
Is it possible to include the ContentTemplate in the Button style?

```
<Window x:Class="CheckBoxStyle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,2,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="CheckBox01">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier" />
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Oblique" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,2,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,0,0" />
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CloseText">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="-3,1,0,0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <CheckBox Content="CB1" />
            <CheckBox Content="CB2" Padding="-1,0,0,0" />
            <CheckBox Content="CB3" Style="{StaticResource CheckBox01}" />
            <CheckBox Content="CB4" Style="{StaticResource CheckBox01}"  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CloseText}"/>
        </StackPanel>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CloseText">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="-1,1,0,0" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
<CheckBox Content="All" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CloseText}"/>
```

as a part of checkbox style (either inline or as resource reference):

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CloseText">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="-3,1,0,0" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,2,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="-3,1,0,0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="CheckBox01">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Oblique" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,2,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CloseText}" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Just one last question please.  Is it possible to include the DataTemplate in a Button Style>

Comment: yes, just declare DataTemplate before Style and add a setter for it